# Idiom/phrase when one takes some share from the shared resources & offers it to others as if he is offering with his own money & appearing generous

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, quotes, proverbs

When Jack takes some leftover beverages (shared-resource) from chip-in that is contributed for a party without other member's consent and are yet required for the coming guests.

Jack then leaves the party to go home. As he approaches his residence building, in  pursuit of his own self-interest, he stops the watchman (who mind the building) and offers the beverages, then goes to the hardware shop attached to the building and offers the beverages to the electrician and the AC technician and other labors who does rectifies his home stuff when they breakdown. This is done so that they feel that Jack is a charitable person who offers then the beverages from his money and are in debt to Jack

What is the idiom/phrase for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Jack is ***taking credit for*** offering the beverages (which he does not completely own) to his acquaintances.

TFD(idioms):

> **[take credit for something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+credit+for)**
>
> to allow people to believe that one has done something praiseworthy,
>   whether or not one has actually done it.
>
> I can't take credit for the entire success. Toby helped a lot.
>   Mary
>   took credit for everything that Dave did.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.